# SQL Server Connection Timeouts

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, sql-server-2019

Every few months one of our web applications starts throwing a timeout exception when running a particular query. This handles searches within the admin section. The strange thing is that when I take the exact same query, I can run it from the SQL Server Management Studio without any issue and it completes within 1 second.

The SQL Server is 2019 and has Query Store running. The query is the 38010 ms for 78 executions in an hour - that doesn't seem too bad?

I asking for suggestion on what tools or features could help track down the source of the timeouts - when they are actually happening?

Comment: You can use Query Store Queries https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4047/sql-server-2016-query-store-queries/